# Latex Beamer does not compile letters in math mode

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I'm using version 3.33 of the `beamer` class (this is the first time I'm using this version), Miktex 2.9 and Texniccenter version 2.0 Alpha 3. I have the problem that letters in math mode do not appear in the output, if I use Latex--> PS --> PDF, as in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{

text $x$ $\alpha$ 

}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: output with x missing]

i.e. the x is missing. If I use Latex--> PDF, a fatal error occurs and no output PDF file is produced.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Show the log-file of the pdf-compilation.

Comment: No problem here either (using TL14 frozen). Does it make any difference if you use `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` instead?

Comment: FWIW, the latest version of [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/) is 3.36, 2015/01/15. Can you update your MikTeX distribution to load the latest versions of all packages, and check if the problem persists once all updates are applied?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a problem caused by using an obsolete version of the document class. After the OP updated his/her TeX distribution, the error went away.