# Error: math mode in Beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I have a problem with letters in math mode in Beamer. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{$A$}
\end{document}
```

When I run this on my office computer, no output is produced. When I run it on my personal computer, it works fine. I use the same version of Beamer on both computers, namely 3.36. Strangely, on the computer where it doesn't work, I have the newest version of MiKTeX (beginning of log: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2015.11.12)), while I have a slightly older version on the computer where it does work (This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=latex 2016.11.9)).

My problem is the same as the one described here: [Latex Beamer does not compile letters in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246018/latex-beamer-does-not-compile-letters-in-math-mode). There the advice is to update to the newest version of Beamer, but I already have that. Do I have to get an older version of MiKTeX to make it work? Or does it have something to do with the "preloaded format", whatever that is? Or are there other possible explanations?

Comment: Does your document compile if you replace `\frame{$A$}` with `\begin{frame}$A$\end{frame}`?

Comment: No, it makes no difference.

Comment: You may have a mismatch between the versions of `beamer` and `latex`. Since you use MikTeX2.9, can you update all packages and formats? I would do this on both machines.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! My installation of MiKTeX is brand new - it's very surprising that it has to be updated to work properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was fixed by updating the OP's latex distribution.